# Any VM supporting Process.supportsNormalTermination==true?

Tags: java, process, kill, java-9

A new feature of Java 9 is that it can not only forcefully kill processes (in the meaning of `SIGKILL`) it had created but it may also support to send a `SIGTERM` (in Java called "normal termination").

According to the documentation of [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#supportsNormalTermination--) one can query if the implementation supports this:

> public boolean supportsNormalTermination​() Returns true if the
>   implementation of destroy() is to normally terminate the process,
>   Returns false if the implementation of destroy forcibly and
>   immediately terminates the process. Invoking this method on Process
>   objects returned by ProcessBuilder.start() and
>   Runtime.exec(java.lang.String) return true or false depending on the
>   platform implementation.

I made some tests using Oracle JRE 9.0.1 (Windows 64bit):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -cp target/classes TestClassWait10Minutes");
p.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(p.supportsNormalTermination());
```

However it seems like Oracle JRE does not supports "normal termination" as I always get `false`.

As it depends on the "platform implementation" it seems that Java 9 defines it but does not implement it.

Does anybody know if the feature of "normal termination" is usable at all in any available Java VM?

Comment: I don't terminate the process, I just wit for 5 seconds. The java program "TestClass" runs 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux implementation, it seems to support normal termination. From the [source of `ProcessImpl`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/23255bc8606d/src/java.base/unix/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java):

```
// Linux platforms support a normal (non-forcible) kill signal.
static final boolean SUPPORTS_NORMAL_TERMINATION = true;

...

@Override

public boolean supportsNormalTermination() {
    return ProcessImpl.SUPPORTS_NORMAL_TERMINATION;
}
```

Not the case on [Windows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/23255bc8606d/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java).

Comment: Looks like Oracle did not want to provide a Windows implementation. AFAIK using `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` it is possible to send a Ctrl+C/SIGTERM to a Windows process via it's console.

Comment: @JMax or maybe there's an actual valid reason. But yeah, they probably didn't **want** to.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8056139 probably addressed this, but is still open.